# Automator PDF contact sheet not using all images

Tags: photos, automator, pdf, services

I've used Automator to create a service that creates all selected images into a contact sheet. For some reason, the service doesn't want to use all the images; I have a selection of 42 images but only 33 get used. This problem persists even when I try to make separate contact sheets of the same 42 images. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: We will likely need to see the script and at least one example of a working image and one example of a non-working image to be of any use. Until then I'm going to flag this question as unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, I actually managed to fix it. All I had to do was log out and then log back in. But if you're interested in the scripts, it was a service with only one workflow which was images to PDF contact sheet. I also selected images from any application.